# How does the union in $\Bbb R^2$ look like?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}n) \times (0,n) \subset \Bbb R^2 $$ be a subset.

I need to know how this look like in $\Bbb R^2 $ for my homework, but I'm not sure.
First I thought that they are intervalls, but someone told me that they are tuples.
So is this the subset {${[0,0) \times (0,\infty)}$} ?

Comment: No, you're right they are intervals. For example $[1/2,1) \times (0.1)$ would be points $(x,y)$ with $1/2 \le x <1,\ 0<y<1.$ [before taking the products, each factor is an interval. After the product, each is a "rectangle" which includes or excludes some of the sides and includes the interior points.

Comment: Also the index beneath the big union symbol should be $n$ and not $i$ And it must start at 1 not 0----

Comment: @coffemath: Thanks I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the left factors are pairwise disjoint with union being $(0,1)$ and the right factors are all open intervals $(0,n),$ the union of the "rectangles" will be the part of the $xy$ plane strictly above the interval $(0,1)$ on the $x$ axis and strictly below a graph obtained by the right ends $n$ of the second factors of the intervals $(0,n).$ For $x$ in $[1/(n+1),1/n)$ the height is constant at $n,$ so (if I did this right) the function is the ceiling of $1/x-1.$ You should check this by sketching the first few rectangles (keeping in mind whether boundaries are included for them).